# Find out Custom List created by user

Tags: custom-list

I need to fetch all custom lists which are created by any end user.

How can I do that?

What I need to do is

Using this:

```
 private void GetAllCustomList()
{
    using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(AppName))
    {
        using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
        {
           // SPListCollection docLibraryColl = oWeb.GetListsOfType(SPBaseType.UnspecifiedBaseType);

            foreach (SPList list in oWeb.Lists)
            {
                if (list.BaseType == SPBaseType.GenericList && list.BaseTemplate == SPListTemplateType.GenericList)
                        Response.Write(list.Title + ", " + list.Author.ToString()  + "<br>");

            }
        }
    }

}
```

but it gives me lots of default List too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Author` property that is available as part of the `SPList` object. You can add a condition as

```
foreach (SPList list in oWeb.Lists)
{
    if(list.Author.LoginName == "domain\username")
        .. //Do the action
```

**Update**

You can do this in two ways

1. Use `SPList.Author.Name == "System Account"` - Assuming "System Account" provisioned the site and its structure
2. Use `SPList.Created > new DateTime(1/1/2015)` - Assuming the site is provisioned on `1/1/2015`

Comment: thanks amal..but I need the list created by any user..not for any specific user..

Comment: sorry didn't quite understand your requirement. Can you please rephrase?

Comment: I just need to get the custom lists those are created by any user and are not the OOTB.

Comment: @dpk I have updated my answer

Comment: amal..SPList.Author.Name == "System Account" by this way we can get the List created by the User...but what about if i want that List type should be only "CUSTOM".

Comment: You can add more conditions some thing like `if(list.Author.Name != "System Account" && list.BaseType == SPBaseType.GenericList)`

Comment: Does not work for me, on some lists it throws an exception: `Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: User cannot be found.`

Answer (score 0):

Filter list.Hidden = false to discard hidden lists...I have modified your code as follows...

```
private void GetAllCustomList()
        {
            using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(AppName))
            {
                using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
                {
                    // SPListCollection docLibraryColl = oWeb.GetListsOfType(SPBaseType.UnspecifiedBaseType);

                    foreach (SPList list in oWeb.Lists)
                    {
                        if (list.BaseType == SPBaseType.GenericList && list.BaseTemplate == SPListTemplateType.GenericList && list.Hidden == false)
                        {

                                Response.Write(list.Title + ", " + list.Author.ToString() + "<br>");

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```